# Magento 2 custom graphql response structure

Tags: magento2.4.4, graphql

How can we generate below response structure in graphql

````
```
{
"results": 
  {
    "itemNames": [
    "prod1 - Name",
    "prod2 - Name",
    "prod3 - Name",
    "prod4 - Name"
    ]
  }
}

```
````

What is the schema.graphqls structure in magento2.4.4?

Answer (score 0):

What entity do you wish to extend with custom data? You can define new fields via `schema.graphqls`. You will have to add new definitions here and potentially create new resolvers for these fields.

There's quite a detailed guide provided by Magento here:

- https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/develop/extend-existing-schema/